# Auto code Completion Not working on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

So I am using the eclipse java ide to do some programming in Java, however the auto comeplete code function isn't working, does anyone know how I can fix this? I've tried adding all the letters in the alphabet to the content assist activation triggers however it now makes a binging noise that you get if you press the spacebar while loading windows. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "isn't working"? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Without information about which Eclipse IDE package you have in which version, what changes you have made in the preferences, how you have configured your project and how to reproduce this issue, it is almost impossible to say what you have done wrong. Showing a screenshot with the Package or Project Explorer and the Java editor would be a good start.